# All routes redirect to /authenticate endpoint in Spring Boot @RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently facing an issue with my Spring Boot application, and I would appreciate some help in resolving it.

I have a JwtAuthenticationController class annotated with @RestController, which has two endpoint mappings: /authenticate and /register. The problem is that every time I try to access any endpoint, I'm always redirected to the /authenticate endpoint, even when I try to access /register.

Here is a simplified version of my JwtAuthenticationController:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class JwtAuthenticationController {
    // Autowired fields and other methods are here (omitted for brevity).

    @PostMapping(value = "/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
        // Authentication logic is here (omitted for brevity).
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveUser(@RequestBody UserRq user) throws Exception {
        // User registration logic is here (omitted for brevity).
    }
}
```

I have verified that both endpoints are correctly mapped with their respective HTTP POST methods. However, whenever I try to access /register, I end up in the /authenticate endpoint.

I have checked my application's logs, but there are no error messages or exceptions related to this issue. It seems like the request is not being properly routed to the /register endpoint.

I've tried restarting the application and checking my request URLs to ensure they are correct. I've also verified that the UserRq class is correctly defined and that the userDetailsService.save(user) method is functioning properly.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this behavior? Any help or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

For more information here is my JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
private final JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

public JwtRequestFilter(JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil,
                        JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService) {
    this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
    this.jwtUserDetailsService = jwtUserDetailsService;
}
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    String username = null;
    String jwtToken = null;
    // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
    // only the Token
    if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
        try {
            username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
        }
    } else {
        logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
    }
    // Once we get the token validate it.
    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
        // authentication
        if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
            // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
            // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}

Here my SecurityConfiguration:

```
  package jb.microservices.login.util;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                        anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                        exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, dont use JWTs as sessions as it is very insecure, thats why there is no such "filter" in spring security. JWTs are not ment to be used as sessions so please remove that. If you are a beginner at spring security, read the official docs and use the tools provided by the framework. Second, `Any help or insights` whats the reason for not enabling DEBUG logs and reading the reason in the logs?

Comment: I've dockerized the microservice with pgadmin at container then I need to deploy and test (I can't access to PostgreSQL container from my IDE don't know why). What kind of session should I use?

Comment: i suggest you do a lot more research https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens https://dzone.com/articles/stop-using-jwts-as-session-tokens https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/ http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/ there are several choices to use instead, how about using one of them that are actually documented in the spring security official documentation? i suggest you read the docs

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try to remake the microservice. :)